# Query result reversing

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following query to retrieve the last 10 results of my database, but I need them not to be in descending order.  Is there anyway I can accomplish this with the query or do I need to handle it in php?  Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT * FROM MSG ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following to resolve your issue

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MSG ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) AS RequiredLimit ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MSG ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10) ORDER BY id -- should work

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the mysql answers that are already there, a php solution would be to use [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) on your original result set.

Answer (score 1):

While using a nested query is one answer, I believe it is more optimum to execute two queries than a nested or a sub-query. Decreases the overhead - correct me if I'm wrong.

I'd suggest:

```
$row_offset = get_result("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSG;") - 10;

$rows = get_result("SELECT * FROM MSG LIMIT " . $row_offset . ", 10;");
```

Assuming (of course!) that get_results() is a custom function executing the query and returning the data from the table.